# how to reuse ie remembered proxy username password

Tags: .net, proxy, registry

- I am writing .Net application, which should connect to a webservice through a proxy (proxy with username password).
- My (All) .net application automatically uses the internet explorer's proxy server settings, **but not proxy username password settings**. Can't i store proxy username password in internet options ?
- Today i used [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) and found that it steals ie's remembered proxy username & password and connects to internet magically. How to do it ? Is there any registry hacks ?
- In other words , **Where IE stores remembered proxy username & password ?** so that i can read it and reuse it.

Comment: Please rephrase as to not sound like you are not doing something evil...